# Error con input en vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Muy buenas, soy novato con vue.js y tengo un pequeño problema:
Consumiendo una api quiero mostrar una lista desordenada en el que muestre el nombre del parametro, y al lado un input con su valor por defecto. La funcion es que si yo modifico ese input me rescate el valor pero al iterar los parametros, al mostrarme los X inputs, cuando modifico uno de modifican todos, por que?

```
<div class="divParameters">
  <ul v-for="(item, index) in this.datosParameters.optimization" :key="index">
    <li class="listParameters">
       {{ index }}
       <input class="inputParameters" :id="index" :name="index" type="text" size="5" v-model.number="optimization">
    </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Entiendo que ves tantos inputs como elementos tenga el array datosParameters.optimization. Todos tendrán diferente ID y diferente NAME, pero el valor de ``v-model`` no cambia nunca, entonces todos los inputs le pegan a la misma variable numerica. Tal vez habria que ver como es esta variable ``optimization``, habria que encontrar la forma de que cada v-model afecte una variable diferente. Algo como ``v-model.number="optimization[index]`` o de ese estilo.

Comment: Para poder darte una respuesta concreta estaría bueno ver las variables ``this.datosParameters`` y ``optimization``, asi como tambien saber donde y como queres almacenar los numeros que se escriben en los input.

Comment: en la primera respuesta me has dado la solucion correcta, habia que ponerlo como array y yo lo tenia como variable normal...un error tonto de base, pero lo que si no puedo es asignarle al input el valor que trae por defecto con :value ya que al parece no puedo compaginarlo con v-model...

Comment: ahi lo puse como respuesta y te dejé un link para que leas porque no podes usar value y v-model. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás usando el mismo `v-model` para todos los inputs. Deberias hacer algo como esto:

```
<div class="divParameters">
  <ul v-for="(item, index) in this.datosParameters.optimization" :key="index">
    <li class="listParameters">
       {{ index }}
       <input class="inputParameters" :id="index" :name="index" type="text" size="5" v-model.number="optimization[index]">
    </li>
 </ul>
```

**Nota:** respecto de tu pregunta en los comentarios sobre `value`, en el siguiente link https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html?redirect=true podes leer lo siguiente

> v-model ignorará los atributos iniciales `value`, `checked` o `selected` encontrados en cualquier elemento del formulario.